# Drools technique for dealing with subsets?

Tags: drools

Let's say I have this list:

```
id| type   | var     
1 | Type A |  4
2 | Type A |  4
3 | Type A |  4
4 | Type A |  4
5 | Type B |  3
6 | Type B |  3
7 | Type B |  3
```

I need to change this to:

```
id| type   | var     
1 | Type A |  7
2 | Type A |  7
3 | Type A |  7
4 | Type A |  7
5 | Type B |  7
6 | Type B |  7
7 | Type B |  7
```

(I'm adding the third column)

```
when
    $listA : ArrayList( ) from collect( Thing(type == 'A') )
    $listB : ArrayList( ) from collect( Thing(type == 'B') )
    erm...
then
    um...
end
```

Anyone have any bright ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited after OP's update**

```
declare SumOfVal
  sum: int
end

rule "computeSum"
when
    not SumOfVal()
    Number( $iv: intValue )
        from accumulate( Thing( $var: var )
                         init( int sum = 0; Set nums = new HashSet(); )
                         action( if( nums.add( $var ) ) sum += $var; )
                         result( sum ) )
then
    insert( new SumOfVal( $iv ) );
end

rule "setSum"
when
    SumOfVal( $sum: sum )
    $t: Thing( var != $sum )
then
    modify( $t ){ setVar( $sum ) }
end
```

The fact `SumOfVal` will have to remain in Working Memory to avoid that the same process is iterated over and over again, unless you have a field in Thing that can be used to indicate that this update has been performed.

Comment: oops, i explained poorly.  7 was just an example, for the case where one set has 3 and the other has 4.  They could be any values.  I need to set them to the sum of the distinct values of those sets.

Comment: OK, please check the modified answer.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't seen that init/action/result code before.  Can I also just check, is there a difference with modify vs. update?  I always use update.

Comment: Does this work now for you? -- modify is preferred. There are some subtle differences, e.g., when changing more than one fact at a time, or (as the Expert manual notes) in combination with "fine grained property change listeners".

Comment: Thanks, good info.  I am redo-ing all my rules in Workbench with the Guided Rule editor so that the business can take part, so won't be testing the code either for about a week.  But I will mark as correct, because I think it will work.